# How to loop over arrays to combine them into one JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have three arrays, "lender", "names", "pageNumbers":

```
var lender = [
    [
        { "name": "IFC", "amount": 50 },
        { "name": "ABC", "amount": 10 }
    ],
    [
        { "name": "DEF", "amount": 40 },
        { "name": "GHI", "amount": 100 }
    ]
]

var names = ["Gary", "Neil", "Luke", "Ben"]

var pageNumbers = [["page 0"], ["page 1"]]
```

I want to combine these three arrays into one JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
page 0 = {
    Gary = {
        financiers = {
            name = IFC
        }
    },
    Neil = {
        financiers = {
            name = ABC
        }
    }
}, page 1 = {
    Luke = {
        financiers = {
            name = DEF
        }
    },
    Ben = {
        financiers = {
            name = GHI
        }
    }
}
```

}

I thought looping over the arrays and assigning them to a predefined object would be the best way to do that:

```
  //Predefined Object
  var lenderObj = {
    "lenders": {
      [pageNumbers]:{
        [names]: {}
      }            
    }

 //Loop
  for (var j = 0; j < pageNumbers.length;j++) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      lenderObj.lenders[pageNumbers[j]] = {
        [names[i]]: {
          financiers:lender[j][i]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I'm not getting the right result, seems to only give me the last name (Ben) and then NULL as the value for 'financiers'. I can't seem to see what is wrong with what I have written. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask you why `pageNumbers` is a two-dimensional array? P.S. you are missing an `=` in `var pageNumbers [["page 0"],["page 1"]]`

Comment: Oops, thanks. pageNumbers is the result of another function that just gives it back multidimensional. I guess it doesn't have to be, if it easier not to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as below -

```js
var lender = [
  [{
      "name": "IFC",
      "amount": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "amount": 10
    }
  ],
  [{
      "name": "DEF",
      "amount": 40
    },
    {
      "name": "GHI",
      "amount": 100
    }
  ]
];

var names = ["Gary", "Neil", "Luke", "Ben"];

var pageNumbers = [
  ["page 0"],
  ["page 1"]
];
var lenderObj = {
  "lenders": {
  }
}

//Loop
var nameIterator = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < lender.length; i++) {
    lenderObj.lenders[pageNumbers[i]] = {};  
  var lenderItem = lender[i];
  for(var j = 0; j < lenderItem.length; j++) {
    lenderObj.lenders[pageNumbers[i]][names[nameIterator]] = {};
    lenderObj.lenders[pageNumbers[i]][names[nameIterator]].financiers = lenderItem[j];
    nameIterator++;
  }
}
console.log(lenderObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` and destructuring

```js
var lender = [
  [
    { name: "IFC", amount: 50 },
    { name: "ABC", amount: 10 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "DEF", amount: 40 },
    { name: "GHI", amount: 100 },
  ],
];

var names = ["Gary", "Neil", "Luke", "Ben"];
var pageNumbers = [["page 0"], ["page 1"]];


const output = { lenders: {} };

pageNumbers.forEach(([page], pi) => {
  output.lenders[page] = {};
  lender[pi].forEach(
    ({ name }, li) =>
      (output.lenders[page][names[2 * pi + li]] = { financiers: { name } })
  );
});

console.log(output);
```